# Can't scroll TreeView inside a ScrollViewer

Tags: wpf, treeview, scrollviewer

I've a TreeView inside a ScrollViewer. 
When I turn the mouse wheel **on the treeview**, treeview is not sliding and it stays at the same point. But when I move the scrollbar, I can slide the treeview.

I'm pretty sure that treeview has a scrollviewer but my point is to use an other scrollviewer is, I've a scrollviwer template and I used this template all over my app. That's why I want to use this template again.

Here is the code:

```
<ScrollViewer Template="{DynamicResource AppleStyleScrollBarStyle}">
    <TreeView>
        <TreeViewItem Header="TreeViewItem"/>
        <TreeViewItem Header="TreeViewItem"/>
        <TreeViewItem Header="TreeViewItem"/>
        <TreeViewItem Header="TreeViewItem"/>
      </TreeView>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: It's because `TreeView` default template already contains `ScrollViewer`. When you wrap `TreeView` in `ScrollViewer` the one inside `TreeView` does nothing but still handles mouse events. Remove outer `ScrollViewer`

Comment: When I remove the outer `ScrollViewer` it works, i know that. If I remove outer `ScrollViewer`, I need to change `TreeView's ScrollViewer` template to `AppleStyleScrollBarStyle` and I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TreeView` default template already contains `ScrollViewer`. When you wrap it in another `ScrollViewer` the one inside `TreeView` does nothing but still handles some mouse events like mouse wheel. Instead you can create implicit `Style` for `ScrollViewer` in `TreeView.Resources`

```xml
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource AppleStyleScrollBarStyle}"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.Resources>
    <TreeViewItem Header="TreeViewItem"/>
    <TreeViewItem Header="TreeViewItem"/>
    <TreeViewItem Header="TreeViewItem"/>
    <TreeViewItem Header="TreeViewItem"/>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: It worked for me. Indeed, removing the ScroViewer makes the TreeView scrolling again. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

This answer helped me:
[WPF Remove ScrollViewer from TreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498686/wpf-remove-scrollviewer-from-treeview?rq=1)

https://serialseb.com/blog/2007/09/03/wpf-tips-6-preventing-scrollviewer-from/

Just subscribe to your treeView's PreviewMouseWheel event:

```
    // https://serialseb.com/blog/2007/09/03/wpf-tips-6-preventing-scrollviewer-from/
    private void treeView_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is TreeView && !e.Handled)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            var eventArg = new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta);
            eventArg.RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseWheelEvent;
            eventArg.Source = sender;
            var parent = ((Control)sender).Parent as UIElement;
            parent.RaiseEvent(eventArg);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Super! I used it for a TreeView in a DockPanel in a StackPanel, just works.