# WPF nested ListViews scrolling behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ListView which contains some other ListViews in it's ItemTemplate definition. What i am looking for is to be able to scroll in the parent list even when the cursor is entered on one of the children's ListView. Because at this moment, this fact ( having the cursor on an inner ListView is preventing the first one to respond ).

Comment: So you don't need to scroll at all on the inner `ListeView`?

Comment: @The inner listview is there jut to host a gridview. And vertically i will not need a scroll. But horizontally yes.

Comment: This answer should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23346121/526704

Comment: @Thank you very much DLeh, that solved the thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont need to be able to scroll in child listview's you need to add to your template

`ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"`