# WPF - Content inside a ScrollViewer element does not touch-scroll when touching a child DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, touch

With the following XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="640">
<ScrollViewer PanningMode="Both">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">LOTS OF TEXT...</TextBlock>
        <DataGrid MinHeight="200">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="100"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="100"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="100"></DataGridTextColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">LOTS OF TEXT...</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

You can  scroll by touching on the `TextBlock`s.  However, if you touch the `DataGrid` and attempt to scroll, it does nothing.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that the content in the `DataGrid` is potentially scrollable itself so WPF is getting confused with the potentially nested scrollbars.

The desired behaviour is that touching in the `DataGrid` will scroll the content inside the `DataGrid` first (if necessary).  Then, when content in the `DataGrid` has been fully scrolled, the main window will scroll.

Comment: `DataGrid` has `ScrollViewer` inside, which capture all scroll events for itself. You will have to bubble corresponding events up, see for insight of how it's done for `MouseWheel` and `ListView` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1585462/1997232).

Comment: Thanks @Sinatr.  The code indeed works for `PreviewMouseWheel`.  However, strangely, it doesn't seem to work for the touch events.  I did a similar thing for `PreviewTouchDown`, `PreviewTouchMove` and `PreviewTouchUp` and the top level `ScrollViewer` still does not scroll.

Comment: Actually, if you just slap a Background=Transparent for hittestvisibility on both your scrollviewers it should automatically scroll chaining. I've never had to actually bubble anything anywhere, and it got even easier in the new stuff where you can just toggle scrollchaining via property.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to PreviewMouseWheel ([Bubbling scroll events from a ListView to its parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585462/bubbling-scroll-events-from-a-listview-to-its-parent)), you can do same with Touch controls:

C#:

```
public sealed class SubControlsTouchScrollEvent : Behavior<UIElement>
{
    double originalDistance;
    double actualDistance;
    int delta;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.PreviewTouchDown += AssociatedObject_PreviewTouchDown;
        AssociatedObject.PreviewTouchMove += AssociatedObject_PreviewTouchMove;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.PreviewTouchUp -= AssociatedObject_PreviewTouchDown;
        AssociatedObject.PreviewTouchMove -= AssociatedObject_PreviewTouchMove;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    void AssociatedObject_PreviewTouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.IInputElement s = sender as System.Windows.IInputElement;
        originalDistance = e.GetTouchPoint(s).Position.Y;
    }

    void AssociatedObject_PreviewTouchMove(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollViewer s = sender as ScrollViewer;
        actualDistance = e.GetTouchPoint(s).Position.Y;
        delta = Convert.ToInt16(actualDistance - originalDistance);          
        s.ScrollToVerticalOffset(s.VerticalOffset - (delta * 0.1));
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer PanningMode="Both" Background="Transparent">
   <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
      <local:SubControlsTouchScrollEvent />
   </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ScrollViewer>
```

NOTE: This is only for vertical scrolling, but you can add horizontal scrolling in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from [@neo_st](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52740465/12748738) worked for me. Three important sidenotes to make this work:

- The Behavior needs to be attached to the outer **ScrollViewer**.
- This solution can't handle MultiTouch. If you put two fingers on the touch screen the Events get fired by both fingers and the vertical scroll doesn't work correctly.
- To get the typical vertical scroll behaviour on the outer **ScrollViewer** you should change the *actualDistance* to the original distance as follows:

```
void AssociatedObject_PreviewTouchMove(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollViewer s = sender as ScrollViewer;
        
        actualDistance = e.GetTouchPoint(s).Position.Y;
        delta = Convert.ToInt16(actualDistance - originalDistance);   
        
        s.ScrollToVerticalOffset(s.VerticalOffset - delta);
        originalDistance = actualDistance;
        
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```