# ListView prevents scrolling of the parent page in WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, scroll

I have a **ListView** in the middle of my page in my WPF application. The problem is when the mouse cursor or my finger is above that ListView then **I can't scroll down on that page** *(the ListView has auto size, no vertical scrolling is needed for it)*. How can I fix this?
Here's what I tried so far:

- setting the **Focusable** property
- setting the **ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility** to all possible values
- changing the **size of the ListView** from auto to a fixed size

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what happens(and why what you tried didnt work), was that the inner ScrollViewer inside the ListView recieved the MouseScroll events.

It handled them and the set for the RoutedEventArgs Handled="True", meaning the Page's ScrollViewer didnt get the scrolling events.

[Bubbling scroll events from a ListView to its parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585462/bubbling-scroll-events-from-a-listview-to-its-parent)

You could take the above and implement it as a Behavior on your ListView.