# Trying to scroll a listbox inside a grid within scrollviewer is not scrolling, in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a xaml page that has a grid with two listbox inside. I want the grid to scroll through the listboxes and this is working, but only if I scroll from outside the listbox area. I want the listboxes to propagate the scroll to the grid, as themselves does not have any scrolling bar.

This is my code:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PinpadPaymentBrandControlList, ElementName=PbUserControl}" x:Name="RadioPbList"
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
             SelectionMode ="Single"
             SelectionChanged="RadioPbList_SelectionChanged">

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
             ...
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate >
        </ListBox>

        <ListBox BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PinpadPaymentBrandControlList, ElementName=PbUserControl}" x:Name="RadioPbList"
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
             SelectionMode ="Single"
             SelectionChanged="RadioPbList_SelectionChanged">

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
             ...
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate >
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I tried using the ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" in the ListBox tag, but it didn't work either.
Any help? I'm not used to using xaml so I might be doing it pretty much wrong

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585462/bubbling-scroll-events-from-a-listview-to-its-parent ?

Comment: No, I wanted to solve this using pure xaml, I don't know if it is possible, though

Comment: Somethings can only be done with code-behind, I guess, like the bubbling of events

Comment: Maybe you're right @fmilani, I'll try using the code-behind, thank you very much for the answer

Comment: ListBoxes have scrollviewers built into their template. I must not be understanding the desired effect. Are you wanting for say a listbox to scroll, hit the end, then parent to scroll to next listbox where then it's scrollviewer takes over?