# bubble scroll event from FlowDocumentScrollViewer to ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, scroll, event-bubbling

I have the following (part of) XAML:

```
    <ListView x:Name="logView" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Logs}"
                               ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <FlowDocumentScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <FlowDocument FontSize="12" FontFamily="Calibri" PagePadding="0" TextAlignment="Left">
                    <Paragraph TextIndent="-10" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                        <Run Text="{Binding .}" />
                    </Paragraph>
                </FlowDocument>
            </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

`Logs` is an `IEnumerable<string>` that the `ListView` is bound to (via a ViewModel, but that shouldn't matter here).

If I remove the whole `<ListView.ItemTemplate>...</ListView.ItemTemplate>`, I have the mouse wheel scrolling behaviour I want. But with the `FlowDocumentScrollViewer` and its content, scrolling does not work as smoothly any more. It still scrolls, but just every now and then, most of the time it gets stuck.

Trying to solve this, I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4342746) solution and created a PreviewMouseWheel handler in the codebehind

```
private void BubbleScrollingToLogView(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Handled)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        var eventArg = new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta);
        eventArg.RoutedEvent = MouseWheelEvent;
        eventArg.Source = sender;
        logView.RaiseEvent(eventArg);
    }
}
```

and added it in the XAML:

```
....
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                          PreviewMouseWheel="BubbleScrollingToLogView">
....
```

But it did not make any change in behaviour. I even tried adding `PreviewMouseWheel="BubbleScrollingToLogView"` to `<FlowDocument>` and `<Paragraph>`, assuming that those might catch the event as well. But nothing helped.

**So what do I need to do to get the smooth, default scrolling behaviour of the `ListView`?**

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you not create a single FlowDocument from the Logs collection and show that in a single FlowDocumentScrollViewer?

Comment: I didn't think about that. Thanks for the suggestion! So now, how to bind a `string` collection to the `FlowDocument` so that each of the `string`s gets it's own paragraph...?

Comment: Add a property to your view model that creates an appropriate FlowDocument. IIRC the Document property of a FlowDocumentScrollViewer might not be bindable. You may need to create an attached property that performs the assignment or some other workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was enough to disable the `FlowDocumentScrollViewer` to get the default scrolling behaviour. I didn't notice any difference in the appearance due to disabling.

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                          IsEnabled="False">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use only `FlowDocumentScrollViewer` you can bind `Document` property to your property on view model.

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer Document="{Binding Document}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
</FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

In your view model define `Document` property of `FlowDocument` type.

```
private FlowDocument document;
public FlowDocument Document
{
    get { return document; }
    set
    {
        document = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Create `FlowDocument` from `Logs`:

```
var doc = new FlowDocument();
doc.FontSize = 12;
doc.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Calibri");
doc.PagePadding = new Thickness(0);
doc.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
foreach (var log in Logs)
{
    var paragraph = new Paragraph(new Run(log));
    paragraph.TextIndent = -10;
    paragraph.Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 0);
    doc.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
}
Document = doc;
```